# What is the oldest known evidence of application of mathematics?

Tags: ho.history-overview

According to Wikipedia the [Lebombo bone (age 35 KY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebombo_bone) and the [Ishango bone (age at least 20 KY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishango_bone) presently are believed to show the first evidence for application of mathematics by humans. (Possibly African women, constructing a moon calendar, were the first mathematicians.) Is this the present state of the art? Or are there newer discoveries of older mathematical artifacts?

Remark: This question is not asking for some examples but for the present state of historical research in paleo-mathematics.

Comment: Just a hint to literature concerning the Ishango Bone (or rather the difficulty to say something about it): http://www.reunion.iufm.fr/recherche/irem/IMG/pdf/Keller_prehistoire_geometrie.pdf

Comment: in this connection, see

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106848/at-what-times-were-people-interested-in-prime-numbers

Comment: @Carlo: Thank you, but I saw it already some time ago (and upvoted your answer). According to Wikipedia there could be prime numbers involved in the interpretation of the Ishango text. But I think that is not very probable. Anyhow would like to know more about these earliest origins of mathematics.

Comment: @unknown: Thank you very much for that interesting source.

Comment: That depends heavily on what you mean by "mathematics". It underwent a sharp transition from the descriptive science to the deductive science sometimes somewhere in the Ancient Greece (it is believed that Thales of Miletus was the first to apply the deductive argument to a geometric problem about 600 BC but we have no proof that nobody did it earlier. Most likely, Thales just was influential enough to get it noticed and followed). This transition was so drastic and had so many implications that I would call everything that preceded it "pre-mathematics". As to mere counting, crows can do it.

Comment: @fedja: I have heard that pigeons can count up to seven (so they can apply the pigeon-hole-principle so far). And Pythagoras' theorem has been known long before himself in Egypt, Babylon and other places. But my question concerns artefacts of arithmetic or geometry that are really older than 30 KY. 

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned geometry. I surmise that this includes distinction between shapes as abstract objects. From this point of view any tool making requiring changing the original shape counts as "an application of math." (and, surprise, crows can do that too :)). We have paleolithic tools from 2.6 million years ago. By the middle paleolithic age, the stone tools were carefully made into the desired shapes. As to Lebombo bone, I'm not sure that if you show a hacksaw or a grate to someone who has no idea what they are for, he'll not declare them counting tools. :)  

Comment: @fedja: If every shaping counts as an application of geometry then every birth counts as an application of arithmetic. I think that is exaggerating a bit, a matter of opinion though.

Comment: I mean not just shaping, but shaping to a certain preset form that is present in the mind and the language. The distinction is subtle and best illustrated by the difference between "Make something pointy" and "Make a disk with two holes symmetric with respect to the center". The first one is not (pre)-math yet but the second already is IMHO. Looking at the tools from middle Paleolithic age, I strongly suspect that it was the second type of instruction they used there commonly. No proof, of course :).